# Css positiong bug on dynamic images

Tags: css, position

I am displaying dynamic images from the database with few details like colour, name and size along them and showing border on hover effect.

1. whenever I hover the mouse on an image,the other images move right or left.I want them to stay there ,where they are.
2. There is unwanted left or right  space  among few pics.

I tried much to fix these issues but no vain.Plz help.

Html code in php function

```
<table id='o4_img_w<?php echo $picid  ?>' style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom: 60px; float: left">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span style="position: relative;top: -100px" ><?php  echo "$pro_col";   ?></span>
      <span><img  src='images/sales/<?php echo $picname  ?>' style='width: 150px'></span>
      <span style="position: relative;top: 15px;left: -100px" ><?php  echo "$pro_name";   ?></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript  in the  php function for hover effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#o4_img_w<?php echo $picid;    ?>").hover(function () {
           $(this).css({
             'border':'solid black 1px',
             'paddingBottom':'30px'
           });

    }, function () {

        $(this).css({
          'border':'none'
        });

    });});

</script
```

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be good... :)

Comment: Where should I begin. That you don't end echo $picid with a semicolon? That you are using inline css and tables for layout? That you add a border to the image on hover (which by the way that's most probably the reason)?

Comment: So, borders have width. Adding 1px border on hover, you are gonna end up with +2 pixels. That's why other images move. Add to other images a border too, the same color as the background color.

Comment: You probably want to change the dom property paddingBottom to be the CSS property padding-bottom while you're at it (in your javascript)

Comment: @MikeSpy thanks for response.But how it ona end with +2px width?

Comment: 1px border to the left + 1px border to the right = 2px + to total width of the image. Follow Viacheslav Dobromyslov's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id='o4_img_w<?=$picid?>' style="border: solid transparent 1px; margin-right:10px;margin-bottom: 60px; float: left">    
<!-- your table stuff -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#o4_img_w<?=$picid?>").hover(function () {
           $(this).css({
             'border-color':'black',
             'paddingBottom':'30px'
           });

    }, function () {
        $(this).css({
          'border-color': 'transparent'
        });
    });});

</script>
```

Use `transparent` or `rgba (0,0,0,0)` border-color to hide the border.

Comment: Thanks,But with your fix, other images move on the first time hover.but stay still after one hovering.

Comment: Edit this also: <img  src='images/sales/<?php echo $picname; ?>' style='width: 150px; border: solid YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR 1px;'>

Comment: @MikeSpy ,now images dont move,but shake/vibrate a little bit,just on first time hovering.

Comment: Just make sure that whatever you have inside the inline style for the image ( width: 150px; border: solid YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR 1px;), you also have it inside the hover and the un-hover states. No differences. Cause jQuery will erase the inline style on hover and add the style you specify.

Comment: @Viacheslav ,Thank you,But why is there unwanted space only right side after two or three images?

Comment: rephrased the answer. now the table has always `border` and jQuery only changes it's color.